extract the telegram profile pictures of a list of phone numbers
I have a list of names with their phone numbers (around 4000 person). I want to get the Telegram profile pictures of these 4000 person and save them in my computer drive/or on my phone hard. profile pictures of each person in a folder. The folder name is the name of the person and his number.
So at end I will have 4000 folder, each folder contain the telegram profile of each person. the name of the folder is the name and the phone number of each person.
I am not familiar with telegram bot and programming in telegram. But I do my best to learn the required basic of this task.
Thanks for any help.

Hi, please take the [tour] and read [ask]. If you are interested in writing your program yourself and need help getting unstuck, that should help you formulate your question/problem statement. If you are interested in someone writing a program to your requirements, this is not the right site for that.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
